# regex to validate server path

Tags: c#, regex, console-application

I can't seem to find regex or other means to validate a sever path   Here is my server path that must exist in following format when I get arguments from c# console app:

> ```
> @"\\myserver\testfolder\tests\"
> ```

I must have `\\` at the beginning

this is how I am passing the value

> ```
> myapp.exe "\\myserver\testfolder\tests\"
> ```

ty np

Comment: Why don't just use [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Backslashes are used for escapes, you will need to double every instance most likely: `\\\\myserver\\testfolder`.

Comment: if you want to do this with regex, you can just escape your '\'s

Comment: Your probably looking for something like: `^(\\\\)[A-Za-z0-9_\\]*$`. Check out http://regexpal.com/ to test it out.

Comment: you can also do [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following. It allows for characters such as `_`, `.`, and `-` in the names, but you might want to adjust those depending on what your server/share names look like. This requires a server and share name, and makes the directory within the share optional.

```
^\\\\[\w\-.]+\\[\w\-.]+\\[\w\-.\\]*$

^\\\\        --> Double-backslash at the beginning
[\w\-.]+\\   --> Server name (at least 1 character) followed by backslash
[\w\-.]+\\   --> Share name (at least 1 character) followed by backslash
[\w\-.\\]*$  --> Directories (0 or more characters including backslashes)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regex, you could use a simple regex like this:

```
\\\\(\w+\\)+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/xY1rL3/2)**

[image]

As you can see, above regex captures the last directory name. If you don't want to capture anything and only match you can set non-capturing group like:

```
\\\\(?:\w+\\)+
```

So, the idea is to have have:

```
\\\\     --> 2 backslashes
(\w+\\)+ --> with one or more directories
```